# How can I set up a working virtual host on MacOs 10.14?

Tags: laravel, xampp, macos-mojave

I'm new to macOS and I'm finding is difficult to setup a virtual host. All tutorials seem to be fore older MacOs versions and not helpful. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome @Kwame. I just searched google and found many results for macos mojave virtual hosts. You should try to explain in your question the issues you are having with the tutorials you have tried.

Comment: I'd start by reading [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead)